# Dictinct Row in queryset using Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, relational-database

I want to remove the duplicate row, distinct row in a Mysql DB.

"Prpk" has a relation with "MeteoZone" (meteozone).

I've a model like this :

```
class MeteoZone(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45, unique=True)
    communes = models.ManyToManyField(Commune, related_name='meteozone', blank=True)
    massifs = models.ManyToManyField(Massif, related_name='meteozone', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Prpk(models.Model):
    begin = models.FloatField()
    end = models.FloatField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    # Relations
    report = models.ForeignKey(Report, on_delete=models.PROTECT, unique=False)
    meteozone = models.OneToOneField(MeteoZone, related_name='prpk', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False, unique=False)
    highway = models.OneToOneField(Highway,related_name='prpk', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, unique=False)
    department = models.OneToOneField(Department,on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, unique=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return ("%s-%s" % (self.begin,self.end))
```

And a serializer :

```
class PrpkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # Get 'meteozones', 'communes' and 'massifs'
    meteozone = MeteozoneSerializer(read_only=True)
    begin = serializers.FloatField()
    end = serializers.FloatField()
    status = serializers.CharField(max_length=15)

    class Meta:
        model = Prpk
        fields = ('begin', 'end', 'status', 'meteozone')
        ordering = ('begin', )
```

In my view, in the query_set, I want to display only the unique records.

```
class PRPKViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows prpk to be viewed
    """
    serializer_class = PrpkSerializer
    queryset = Prpk.objects.all().order_by('begin').distinct()
    # Authentification !
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    # Only 'get' method
    http_method_names = ['get']

    @method_decorator(vary_on_cookie)
    @method_decorator(cache_page(60*60*1))
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self):
        """ allow rest api to filter by submissions """
        #queryset = Prpk.objects.all().order_by('begin').values_list('begin', flat=True).distinct()
        queryset = Prpk.objects.all().order_by('begin').distinct()
        highway = self.request.query_params.get('highway', None)
        if highway is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(highway=highway)

        return queryset
```

Look at a part of records :

```
id     begin    end    status  commune_id   department_id   highway_id  massif_id   meteozone_id    report_id
76      25      25.6    1        NULL           13            2          45             40            1
77      25      25.6    1        NULL           13            2          161            40            1
```

In this records, I just one **only one** record in json, but DRF returns 2 records, like this :

```
[
    {
        "begin": 25,
        "end": 25.6,
        "status": "1",
        "meteozone": {
            "communes": [],
            "massifs": [
                {
                    "id": 45,
                    "name": "abc"
                },
                {
                    "id": 161,
                    "name": "def"
                }
            ],
            "id": 40,
            "name": "133"
        }
    },
    {
        "begin": 25,
        "end": 25.6,
        "status": "1",
        "meteozone": {
            "communes": [],
            "massifs": [
                {
                    "id": 45,
                    "name": "abc"
                },
                {
                    "id": 161,
                    "name": "def"
                }
            ],
            "id": 40,
            "name": "133"
        }
    },
    {
```

I add a "distinct" method, but it's not working. Can U help me please ? :)

F.

Comment: ".distinct('begin','end','status','meteozone')" not working : "NotImplementedError: DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend"

Comment: I can remove the duplicate in the json (but after the query) like this : " prpk_by_highway = {each['begin']: each for each in prpk_by_highway}.values()" But it's not efficient and the values aren't in the initial order !! :(